# Reduce size of an image when it is fusioned with other using ImageMagick from terminal in Linux

Tags: terminal, imagemagick, composite

I am having these two pictures, labeled `1.png` and `2.png`, respectively:

[image]
[image]

When I run this code from ImageMagick in my Linux terminal:

```
composite -blend 75 -gravity West  2.png  1.png prueba.png
```

I get this result:

[image]

However, I would like the logo (`2.png`) to be half or one-third size reduced and placed in the bottom left corner. How can I do it from the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in ImageMagick by using the convert syntax. It is more flexible than the composite syntax.

```
convert 1.png \( 2.png -resize 50% \) -gravity southwest -define compose:args=75 -compose blend -composite 1_2.png
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! It worked pretty nicely. One last question. Is there any possibility to place the logo out of the boundaries? I mean, in the picture you created to move even further to the left so that part of it is not present in the final picture

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move it further left, you can simply chop off some of the left side before compositing using ImageMagick.

```
convert 1.png \( 2.png -resize 50% -gravity west -chop 20x0 \) -gravity southwest -define compose:args=75 -compose blend -composite 1_2_b.png
```

[image]

Alternately, you can simply trim the excess empty space around the 2.png before blending.

```
convert 1.png \( 2.png -resize 50% -trim +repage \) -gravity southwest -define compose:args=75 -compose blend -composite 1_2_c.png
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your quick response. They been totally illustrative!